Powershell: How to copy, duplicate, or clone an object?
I'm banging my head against the wall.  I have an issue where I'm dealing with objects created using the AWS Powershell Tools, specifically objects of type Amazon.Route53.Model.ResourceRecordSet and Amazon.Route53.Model.ResourceRecord.
I have a case where I'm pulling a resource record set from AWS Route53 and I need to modify the list of resource records and then resubmit it back to AWS.  I've been doing this by simply retrieving and modifying a single resourcerecordset object and that is working.
However I want to instead leave the existing object untouched and create a copy of it that I would then modify.  Essentially, something like
$NewR53ResourceRecordSet = $CurrentR53ResourceRecordSet

I've come to realize that this assignment creates a reference type so the original is modified when I modify the new.  I cannot find any way to create a copy of this object.  Research suggests using .Clone() but apparently that's not implemented on these object types.
I ended up having to do the following, which seems excessively unnecessary.
$NewR53ResourceRecordSet = New-Object Amazon.Route53.Model.ResourceRecordSet
$NewR53ResourceRecordSet.Name = $CurrentR53ResourceRecordSet.Name
$NewR53ResourceRecordSet.Type = $CurrentR53ResourceRecordSet.Type
$NewR53ResourceRecordSet.TTL = $CurrentR53ResourceRecordSet.TTL
foreach ($CurrentR53ResourceRecord in $CurrentR53ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords) {
    $NewR53ResourceRecord = New-Object Amazon.Route53.Model.ResourceRecord
    $NewR53ResourceRecord.Value = $CurrentR53ResourceRecord.Value
    $NewR53ResourceRecordSet.ResourceRecords += $NewR53ResourceRecord
}


Why is this such a difficult thing to do in Powershell?  I've seen the following so I understand some of what's happening, I just don't understand why there's no obvious solution to what I would think is something as simple as cloning an object.
PowerShell Function parameters - by reference or by value?

"something as simple as cloning an object" isn't as simple as you think, specially when a reference type has reference type members.

Obviously, otherwise it would have been done.  I'm asking why.  In my ignorant mind, this is just simple data stored in memory.  Why can't it simply be copied?  A computer and its programs perform way more complicated tasks than this every day, do they not?

.Clone is an implementation detail, the developer might implement IClonable in their type but the method just return a shallow copy of the object or they might implement a deep copy. It's always up to the developer how they want to implement the interface. For the specific case of Amazon.Route53.Model.ResourceRecordSet type, the developers might've thought that cloning was too hard or they were lazy to implement it. It's not an answer we can give you. See the Notes to implementers

Yeah I've read up on the .Clone implementations and that being a choice of the developer.  I just didn't understand the difficulty, but I think I do now after getting some more detailed information (albeit from ChatGPT, so not sure how factual it is).

Since this type has reference types members, it might have just been too hard because all reference types members down the member hierarchy would have to be cloneable too.

Makes sense.  Thank you.

As commented by @SantiagoSquarzon, it isn't always that simple.
Unfortunately, I have no clue where of the structure of the Amazon.Route53.Model.ResourceRecordSet object and which types it exists of. As you not sharing the source of the objects (presumably for the same reason you aren't able to copy them). I am afraid that they contain some non-DTOs (Data Transfer Objects) property objects, yet the word ResourceRecordSet, suggest that it might just concern DTOs.
Anyways, a general way to deep copy an object might be blindly serializing and deserializing the object:
Via the Json serializer:
$NewObject = $Object | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 | ConvertFrom-Json

Via the PowerShell (CliXml):
$CliXml = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($Object, 10)
$NewObject = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($CliXml)

Knowing that serializing and deserializing an object is somewhat cumbersome (from a technical standpoint), slow and might also cause some side effects (take e.g. #14264), besides you probably also want to do something with the copied object (as changing some values based on others and eventually convert or export it). From this view, I created a ObjectGraphTools module with some PSNode classes and cmdlets along with a Copy-ObjectGraph that deep copies a complex object-graph:
$NewObject = $Object | Copy-ObjectGraph

In case the original does contain any non-DTOs, you might consider to use the -ListAs @() and -MapAs @{} parameters but I am not sure whether the result will still be useful for you.

ChatGPT suggested the ConvertTo-Json route but when I tried to pull it back in with ConvertFrom-Json, it errored.  I didn't look any further though.  I did not specify the depth parameter you did, though.  Perhaps that had something to do with it.
In this case, fortunately the ResourceRecord itself just has a single string property so I ended up creating the new resourcerecordset object, copying the simple properties, and when it came to resourcerecords, looped through each creating new resourcerecords copying their own property.  This just seems unnecessary.

I guess ChatGPT didn't read Unexpected ConvertTo-Json results? Answer: it has a default -Depth of 2

You got jokes, huh?  lol

Well I had a pretty explanatory answer that could have been useful to others who had the same question, but because it was sourced from AI, it was deleted by moderators.
The information could have been voted on in terms of accuracy vs flat out removing it.
At this point you might as well delete the entire question then, as it's likely no one else will answer it with that level of detail and if they do it'll likely be pretty much the same information that was already pasted and likely be flagged as AI generated as well.  So dumb.
